# Matplotlib modified histograms won't display after modification

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, histogram

I have plotted a histogram and would like to modify it, then re-plot it. It won't plot again without redefining the `Figure` and `Axes` object definitions. I'm using Jupyter Notebook, and I'm new to matplotlib, so I don't know if this is something that I'm not understanding about matplotlib, if it's an issue with the Jupyter Notebook or something else.

Here's my 1st block of code:

```
"""Here's some data."""
some_data = np.random.randn(150)
"""Here I define my `Figure` and `Axes` objects."""
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
"""Then I make a histogram from them, and it shows up just fine."""
ax.hist(some_data, range=(0, 5))
plt.show()
```

Here's the output from my 1st block of code:

[image: Histogram_output_1]

Here's my 2nd block of code:

```
"""Here I modify the parameter `bins`."""
ax.hist(some_data, bins=20, range=(0, 5))
"""When I try to make a new histogram, it doesn't work."""
plt.show()
```

*My 2nd block of code generates **no visible output**, which **is the problem**.*

Here's my 3rd and final block of code:

```
"""But it does work if I define new `Figure` and `Axes` objects. 
Why is this? 
How can I display new, modified plots without defining new `Figure` and/or `Axes` objects? """
new_fig, new_ax = plt.subplots()
new_ax.hist(some_data, bins=20, range=(0, 5))
plt.show()
```

Here's the output from my 3rd and final block of code:

[image: Histogram_from_3rd_block]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the inline backend; so you can replace `plt.show()` by `fig` in the second codeblock.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest. I did what you suggested and used `fig` instead of `plt.show()` (you can see that I commented out `plt.show()` in the code block below). The issue is that the new modified plot is on top of the original plot. Is there any way to replace the original with the modified plot? Here's the code:

`ax.hist(some_data, bins=20, range=(0, 5))`

`# plt.show()`

`fig`



Here's the output [Modified Hist](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfst0i4na3ydvxo/histogram3.png?dl=0)

Comment: If you do not create a new figure, it will show in the old one, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you generate a figure or an axis, it remains accessible for rendering or display until it's used for rendering or display. Once you execute `plt.show()` in your first block, the `ax` becomes unavailable. Your 3rd block of code is showing a plot because you're regenerating the figure and axes.

Comment: Thanks @Yaakov Bressler. So is there any way of rendering updated versions of a plot without to redefine it similarly to how you could view updated versions of a DataFrame in pandas?

Comment: You can try plotting onto the initialized `fig` which isn't dissipated on in the `plt.show()` command. Otherwise, I'd suggest replotting and re-showing, unless this is against the goal of the project in which case you should consider subplots.

Comment: Thanks you, much appreciated!